# Proper way to execute an executable file (.exe) in different situations

Tags: java, process, runtime, classpath, execution

this sort of problem is bugging me already for a while, so I was curious how your approaches are to handle the following situation:

Imagine I have two different eclipse projects in same workspace called ProjectA and ProjectB. ProjectB contains a .exe-file within its root, which is called from ProjectA the following way:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "../ProjectB/ProjectB.exe" );
```

The problem now is, that after deployment the structure slightly changes: ProjectA is now a .jar. Next to that jar is now a folder with ProjectB, which contains ProjectB with its .exe, .jars and so on. Now the proper call would have to look like the following:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "ProjectB/ProjectB.exe" );
```

Since I need these structures to stay like they are, and I dont want two different .exec calls within my application for each case I tried several things to work around this situation:

1) Adding ProjectB as ClassFolder to ProjectA and letting the ContextClassLoader figuring out, where to find ProjectB.exe like this:

```
URL url= Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource( "ProjectB.exe" );
file = new File( url.toURI() );
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( file.getAbsolutePath() );
```

This solution worked perfectly fine until I tried to deploy my application on a network drive.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

2) Since I won`t be allowed to create a network drive for each client, I tried to work around this problem and did the following:

```
URL url= Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource( "ProjectB.exe" );
File file = new File( url.getFile() );
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( file.getAbsolutePath() );
```

This seemed promissing, but unfortunatly just as long as my path stayed without dashes(" "), since this appraoch seemed to convert every dash into "%20", which the runtimeexecutor doesnt really seem to like. Of course I could replace every "%20" into " " afterwards, but this seems kinda hacky to me.

Another requirement is, that both application have to run in a different JVM, which is why I call the .exe-file by Runtimeexecution. So my final question is: Is there any way to get the ProjectB calls clean without any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way is to define a search path (several `File` instances which point to different directory). Append the exe's name to each path and check if the resulting `File` exists and use that path to execute it.

The exception is from Windows' security layer: It doesn't allow to run unknown exe files from a network path. See your sysadmin for a solution.

Note that you can't always load exe's from the classpath. For example if they are inside of a JAR, it won't work. Windows' launcher doesn't know how to handle JAR files. The solution here is to unpack the resource to a temporary file and start it from there.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to get through my question. The idea to work with search pathes is interesting. I still dislike, that I first have to identify the real position of the .exe-file, but its still a simple and satisfying solution. I dont know why I didnt come up with it myself.